# Operation not permitted - probably not a Full Disk Access issue

Tags: bash, iterm, sip

I've given both iterm and bash (both bashes - one is from homebrew) Full Disk Access, but I still see:

```
$ find /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db
cmd output started 2021 Mon Jun 14 10:03:24 PM PDT
/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db: Operation not permitted
```

And there don't appear to be any special flags set on it:

```
$ ls -lO /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/
cmd output started 2021 Mon Jun 14 10:12:22 PM PDT
total 0
drwx------  3 _networkd  _networkd  -  96 Jan 12 11:49 Library
drwxr-xr-x  5 _networkd  _networkd  - 160 Jan 12 11:50 db
```

And the permissions bits seem pretty normal:

```
$ python3
cmd output started 2021 Tue Jun 15 08:27:38 AM PDT
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 03:36:27)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> oct(os.stat('/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db').st_mode)
'0o40755'
>>>
```

What do I need to do to give find the ability to traverse this directory without an error?

Thanks!